# Swift iOS -How to map results from Flashlight/ElasticSearch tutorial to UISearchController?

Tags: ios, swift, elasticsearch, firebase-realtime-database, uisearchcontroller

Following the steps from https://github.com/firebase/flashlight how would I map the results that `flashlight` pulls from `Firebase Database` to get shown inside my `SearchController`?

data model:

```
class Sneakers: NSObject{
    var name: String?
    var condition: String?
}
```

SearchController:

```
class SearchViewController: UIViewController, UITableViewDataSource, UITableViewDelegate, UISearchResultsUpdating, UISearchBarDelegate, UISearchControllerDelegate {

@IBOutlet weak var tableView: UITableView!

var searchController: UISearchController!
var userContent = [Sneakers]()
var filteredSearchSneakerNames = [Sneakers]()
var filteredSearchSneakerConditions = [Sneakers]()

override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        self.searchController = UISearchController(searchResultsController: nil)
        //search controller initializers...
        self.tableView.reloadData()
}

deinit{
        self.searchController = nil
}

func tableView(tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {

        let scopeButtonIndex = self.searchController.searchBar.selectedScopeButtonIndex

        if scopeButtonIndex == 0{
            return self.filteredSearchSneakerNames.count
        }else{
            return self.filteredSearchSneakerConditions.count
        }
}

func tableView(tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
        let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier("SearchCell", forIndexPath: indexPath)

        let scopeButtonTitles = self.searchController.searchBar.selectedScopeButtonIndex

        if scopeButtonTitles == 0 {
            let searchString = self.filteredSearchSneakerNames[indexPath.row]

            cell.textLabel?.text = searchString.name
            cell.detailTextLabel?.text = ""
        }else{
            let searchString = self.filteredSearchSneakerConditions[indexPath.row]

            cell.textLabel?.text = searchString.name
            cell.detailTextLabel?.text = searchString.condition
        }
        return cell
}

func didPresentSearchController(searchController: UISearchController) {
        self.searchController.searchBar.becomeFirstResponder()
}

func searchBarTextDidBeginEditing(searchBar: UISearchBar) {
        self.tableView.reloadData()
}

func updateSearchResultsForSearchController(searchController: UISearchController) {

        self.filteredSearchSneakerNames.removeAll(keepCapacity: false)
        self.filteredSearchSneakerConditions.removeAll(keepCapacity: false)

        let searchText = searchController.searchBar.text

        let scopeButtonIndex = self.searchController.searchBar.selectedScopeButtonIndex

        if scopeButtonIndex == 0{

            let searchPredicate = NSPredicate(format: "SELF.name CONTAINS[c]%@", searchText!)

            let array = (self.userContent as NSArray).filteredArrayUsingPredicate(searchPredicate)
            self.filteredSearchSneakerNames = array as! [Sneakers]
        }else{

            let searchPredicate = NSPredicate(format: "SELF.condition CONTAINS[c]%@", searchText!)

            let array = (self.userContent as NSArray).filteredArrayUsingPredicate(searchPredicate)
            self.filteredSearchSneakerConditions = array as! [Sneakers]
        }
        self.tableView.reloadData()
}
```